# How to search words by order in matrix (list) by python

Tags: python

How to do that?
i mean it is some kind of search on the matrix. I need to search **search_matrix** on **main_matrix**.
Special rule is: if **search_matrix** is a included in beginning 4 elements of **main_matrix** then it can be a output. I mean if **search_matrix** is not in **main_matrix's** beginning (4 elements) it cannot be a in **output_matrix**.
and element order is most important. elements must be in order.

```
main_matrix = 
 [['AAA', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
 ['ccc', 'AAA', 'bbb'],
 ['DDD', 'AAA', 'fff', 'ccc', 'hhhh', 'iii'],
 ['JJJ', 'kkk', 'lll', 'mmm', 'nnn', 'ooo'],
 ['PPP', 'qqq', 'rrr', 'sss', 'tttt', 'yyy'],
 ['mmm', 'kkk'],
 ['bbb', 'zzz', 'sss']]
 ['kkk', 'qqq', 'rrr', 'mmm', 'ttt', 'yyyyyy'],
 ['PPP', 'qqq', 'rrr', 'mmm', 'ttt', 'yyy'],
 ['zzz', 'zzzz', 'zzz', 'zzz', 'AAA', 'ccc']]

search_matrix=
 [['AAA', 'ccc'],
 ['bbb', 'ccc'],
 ['kkk', 'mmm'],
 ['PPP','qqq', 'rrr']]
```

Desired output is:

```
output_matrix = 
     [['AAA', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
     ['DDD', 'AAA', 'fff', 'ccc', 'hhh', 'iii'],
     ['AAA', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
     ['JJJ', 'kkk', 'lll', 'mmm', 'nnn', 'ooo'],
     ['kkk', 'qqq', 'rrr', 'mmm', 'ttt', 'yyy'],
     ['PPP', 'qqq', 'rrr', 'sss', 'ttt', 'yyy']]
```

Please help me?

**Update:**

can we do it on last 3 elements?

Comment: Please provide more details of your desired procedure, e.g an example with one String or List

Comment: I don't understand why  in the output `['AAA', 'bbb', 'ccc']` occurs twice?

Comment: @fsimonjetz because it includes ['AAA', 'ccc']  and ['bbb', 'ccc']

Comment: Ah I see, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by first 4 Elements? Of the `main_matrix`, or its own lists?

Comment: @Raumschifffan if you carefully see to desired output then you will understand easily

Comment: Ok, I think I got it

Comment: And why is `['PPP','qqq', 'rrr']` not returning last two as well?

Comment: @Raumschifffan please refresh your browser i edited it

Comment: I think you also got some extra `]`s there? `main_matrix` is just a plain 2d matrix right?

Comment: @fsimonjetz yes its 2D matrix. i edited it please refresh your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
main_matrix = [
    ['AAA', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
    ['ccc', 'AAA', 'bbb'],
    ['DDD', 'AAA', 'fff', 'ccc', 'hhh', 'iii'],
    ['JJJ', 'kkk', 'lll', 'mmm', 'nnn', 'ooo'],
    ['PPP', 'qqq', 'rrr', 'sss', 'ttt', 'yyy'],
    ['mmm', 'kkk'],
    ['bbb', 'zzz', 'sss'],
    ['kkk', 'qqq', 'rrr', 'mmm', 'ttt', 'yyy'],
    ['PPP', 'qqq', 'rrr', 'mmm', 'ttt', 'yyy'],
    ['zzz', 'zzz', 'zzz', 'zzz', 'AAA', 'ccc']
]

search_matrix = [
    ['AAA', 'ccc'],
    ['bbb', 'ccc'],
    ['kkk', 'mmm'],
    ['PPP', 'qqq', 'rrr']
]

output_matrix = []


def s(search, it):
    indices = []
    for el in search:
        if el in it:
            indices.append(it.index(el))
        else:
            return False
    if indices != sorted(indices):
        return False
    return True


for foo in search_matrix:
    for bar in main_matrix:
        if s(foo, bar[:4]):
            output_matrix.append(bar)
```

Think I got it, gives the output

```
[['AAA', 'bbb', 'ccc'], ['DDD', 'AAA', 'fff', 'ccc', 'hhh', 'iii'], ['AAA', 'bbb', 'ccc'], ['JJJ', 'kkk', 'lll', 'mmm', 'nnn', 'ooo'], ['kkk', 'qqq', 'rrr', 'mmm', 'ttt', 'yyy'], ['PPP', 'qqq', 'rrr', 'sss', 'ttt', 'yyy'], ['PPP', 'qqq', 'rrr', 'mmm', 'ttt', 'yyy']]
```

Comment: If there's need for it, I will later explain the steps

Comment: can we do it on not beginning 4 elements. i mean can we do it on last 3 elements?

Comment: Locate this and chnge it to whatever you like `bar[:4]` (Last 3) `bar[-3:]`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that it's a solution, but just to understand: Is this the result you're after?

```
from itertools import combinations

for row in main_matrix:
    for search_row in search_matrix:
        search_row = tuple(search_row)
        for combo in combinations(row[:4], len(search_row)):
            if combo == search_row:
                print(row, "includes", combo)
```

prints:

```
['AAA', 'bbb', 'ccc'] includes ('AAA', 'ccc')
['AAA', 'bbb', 'ccc'] includes ('bbb', 'ccc')
['DDD', 'AAA', 'fff', 'ccc', 'hhh', 'iii'] includes ('AAA', 'ccc')
['JJJ', 'kkk', 'lll', 'mmm', 'nnn', 'ooo'] includes ('kkk', 'mmm')
['PPP', 'qqq', 'rrr', 'sss', 'ttt', 'yyy'] includes ('PPP', 'qqq', 'rrr')
['kkk', 'qqq', 'rrr', 'mmm', 'ttt', 'yyy'] includes ('kkk', 'mmm')
['PPP', 'qqq', 'rrr', 'mmm', 'ttt', 'yyy'] includes ('PPP', 'qqq', 'rrr')
['PPP', 'qqq', 'rrr', 'mmm', 'AAA', 'ccc'] includes ('PPP', 'qqq', 'rrr')
```

But it's not exactly what you require?

Comment: i will test it tommorrow. but thank you. so word order is important in your solution right?

Comment: Yes, `itertools.combinations` only gives you combinations in order.

Comment: can we do it on not beginning 4 elements. i mean can we do it on last 3 elements?

Comment: how to get all 'row' outputs? your code print all 'row' outputs but i can't store all 'row' outputs.

Comment: As you can see, `row[:4]` takes a slice of the row with only the first four elements, so you need to change that to get the last three. This wasn't meant to be a solution, it's probably very inefficient, but if you want to store the result, make a list before the loop like `result = []` and replace the `print`-statement with `result.append(row)`.